# How can java application (macOS Catalina) request access to network volume?

Tags: java, file-permissions, macos-catalina, disk

My app is completely written in java (we moved to java11 from java8) and was running fine under High Sierra: 
`new RandomAccessFile(file_on_network_volume, "rws")` gained access and execution continued.

Running under **Catalina** it fails with 
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Volumes/messages/xyz/FILE.xdt (Operation not permitted)`

I understand that any application trying to access a network volume needs a special permission, I reviewed them in System Preferences and they can be removed with `tccutil reset SystemPolicyNetworkVolumes [bundle_id]` for repeated testing.

How does the java code properly request the access right from the user so that the processing might continue?

What I did so far:

- changed the code to 
  `AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedExceptionAction<RandomAccessFile>) () -> new RandomAccessFile(file, "rws"));` 
  That caused a JUnitTest run with IntelliJ to request the right by a dialogue  
  An application in IntelliJ IDEA requests access to files on a network volume

[image: An application in IntelliJ IDEA requests access to files on a network volume]

then the test succeeded to do the required operation on the network  volume. 
The effect is the permission indicated in system preferences as expected: 
permission to access network volumes is present

[image: permission to access network volumes is present]

- added in the Info.plist the entry 
  `<key>NSNetworkVolumesUsageDescription</key> <string>@@bundle_name@@ benötigt Zugriff auf ein Netzwerkvolume.</string>` 
  corresponding to the text in the dialog displayed to the user

But still something's missing. The app **does not** request the permission and consequently the operation fails. IntelliJ does something right that I didn't figure out so far.

Comment: I'm also wondering about this one. In my case, the application is not one that is started and stopped by a user but rather a process that is started by another process which in turn is running as a daemon in the background (using a .plist file stored in /Library/LaunchDaemons). So in this case, even if I could get it to request the permission, how would a popup for requesting permission even be displayed to a user?
Surely Apple, you must provide a way for a user to grant such permission to a certain executable up-front and not just reactively when that executable is executed?